# Xamarin: Grouped ListView not binding delete Command using MVVM

Tags: listview, xamarin, binding, icommand, grouped-list

I'm getting crazy trying to bind a Command in order to remove an item from a grouped ListView.
My ViewModels inherit from a BaseViewModel in order to ease the notification of a changing property.
I followed the common approach that seems to be the correct one by using two ObservableCollections.

Those are my ViewModels, that are displayed correctly, but I cannot bind the RemoveCommand to each item (of type ArticleForOrdineOTIVM). I used the constructor for creating dummy objects.
I tried every sort of combination in my xaml file within Command="", for example by pointing Source reference to the listview name, but I can't make it work. It always says like i cannot reach the scope of the inner Context, but at most I can bind a command within OrderOTIVM, no further (for example the Command "TestCommand"). I need to do this because I want to remove, edit and do stuff inside each item of the list, and the error explained before says:

Binding: 'RemoveCommand' property not found on 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[BrScanner.ViewModels.GroupedArticlesVM]', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Button.Command'

In the View file I set the BindingContext as:

```
public partial class OrderOTIView : ContentPage
    {
        public OrderOTIView()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
        OrderOTIVM orderOTIViewModel = new OrderOTIVM();
            BindingContext = orderOTIViewModel;
        }
    }
```

These are my ViewModels:

```
public class OrderOTIVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        ObservableCollection<GroupedArticlesVM> _carrelliGrouped;
        public ObservableCollection<GroupedArticlesVM> CarrelliGrouped { get => _carrelliGrouped; set {  _carrelliGrouped = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
        }

        public OrderOTIVM()
        {
            CarrelliGrouped = new ObservableCollection<GroupedArticlesVM>();
            GroupedArticlesVM car1 = new GroupedArticlesVM();
            car1.Carrello.Nome = "Carrello A";
            CarrelliGrouped.Add(car1);

            GroupedArticlesVM car2 = new GroupedArticlesVM();
            car2.Carrello.Nome = "Carrello B";
            CarrelliGrouped.Add(car2);

        }
    public Command TestCommand
            {
                get
                {
                    return new Command(
                        (x) => {
                            Debug.WriteLine("TestCommand");
                        });
                }
            }
    }

    public class GroupedArticlesVM :  ObservableCollection<ArticleForOrdineOTIVM>
    {
        CarrelloMinimarketVM _carrello;
        public CarrelloMinimarketVM Carrello { get => _carrello; set { _carrello = value; } }

        public GroupedArticlesVM()
        {
            Items.Add(new ArticleForOrdineOTIVM());
            Items.Add(new ArticleForOrdineOTIVM());
            Items.Add(new ArticleForOrdineOTIVM());
            Items.Add(new ArticleForOrdineOTIVM());

            Carrello = new CarrelloMinimarketVM();
        }


        public Command<ArticleForOrdineOTIVM> RemoveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command<ArticleForOrdineOTIVM>(
                    (articolo)=>{
                        Items.Remove(articolo);
                });
            }
        }

    }

    public class CarrelloMinimarketVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        string _nome;

        public CarrelloMinimarketVM()
        {
            this.Nome = "CARRELLO";
        }

        public string Nome { get => _nome; set { _nome = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    public class ArticleForOrdineOTIVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        string _oarti;
        string _tarti;
        int _amount;

        public string Oarti { get => _oarti;    set {   _oarti = value;     OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public string Tarti { get => _tarti;    set {   _tarti = value;     OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public int Amount { get => _amount;     set {   _amount = value;    OnPropertyChanged(); } }

        public ArticleForOrdineOTIVM()
        {
            this.Oarti = "Oarti blabla";
            this.Tarti = "Descrizione blabla";
            this.Amount = 22;
        }  
    }
```

This is my Xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="BrScanner.Views.OrderOTIView"
             x:Name="OrderOTIPage"
             >
            <ListView x:Name="carrelliListView" ItemsSource="{Binding CarrelliGrouped}"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Carrello.Nome}"
                      IsGroupingEnabled="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Oarti}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Tarti}"/>
                                <Button Text="cancella" 

                                        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CarrelliGrouped.RemoveCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=OrderOTIPage}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My BaseViewModel:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: In your case , `CarrelliGrouped ` is an **ObservableCollection** , not a **GroupedArticlesVM** . It would be better to define it in VM like TestCommand .

Answer (score 1):

According to the binding expression in your command

```
Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CarrelliGrouped.RemoveCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=OrderOTIPage}}"
```

The **RemoveCommand** should be found on the property **CarrelliGrouped** in the ViewModel **OrderOTIVM**.

But **CarrelliGrouped** is an ObservableCollection, not a **GroupedArticlesVM**.

Thus the error, RemoveCommand can not be found on an ObservableCollection.

To solve your problem, you should move RemoveCommand in OrderOTIVM. And in the command, you should add some logic to lookup in the list to find the item you want to remove.

Your XAML would look like this :

```
Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.RemoveCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=carrelliListView}}"
```